# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class xxx.xxx.xxx.HibernateUtil

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey

Herewith I added my source code of web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>ussd</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>init</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/init.jsp</jsp-file>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.dialog.mife.ussd.api.USSDApplication</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>com.dialog.mife.ussd.exception.NotFoundException</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml.
My Web service project goes with Jersey+Hibernate..

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>   
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/USSD</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>   
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.Application" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is HibernateUtil Class

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Here is my error
I added Hibernate latest jar files.
[**hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar**]

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.dialog.mife.ussd.util.HibernateUtil
    at org.apache.jsp.init_jsp.jspInit(init_jsp.java:23)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:48)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Nov 11, 2014 2:06:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /ussd threw load() exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.dialog.mife.ussd.util.HibernateUtil
    at org.apache.jsp.init_jsp.jspInit(init_jsp.java:23)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:48)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Please help me to sort out this issue
thanks

Comment: Can u update question with `web.xml` ?

Comment: Dear OO7
I Added web.xml

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This Kind of error can happen when initializing `SessionFactory` fails. You have mentioned that you are using `hibernate-core-4.3.7`. The way you are initializing the `SessionFactory` is not the correct for this version. Use *Hibernate* version 3.x  or change the way you are initializing the `SessionFactory`. Below is the correct way to build the session factory in `Hibernate 4.x +`.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

Comment: Thanks prageeth..its worked for me.you saved my day.!
seems issue is Hibernate version conflict.Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

According [codejava.net](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/building-hibernate-sessionfactory-from-service-registry) the HibernateUtil for `hibernate-core-4.x` looks like this:

```
...
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            // loads configuration and mappings
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
                = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // builds a session factory from the service registry
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);           
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
....
```

It is slightly optically different than example above, but the effect is the same. It is needed, to ensure, that old dictionary `hibernate-3.x` is really not present.

Answer (score 0):

Some classes are missing when com.dialog.mife.ussd.util.HibernateUtil class is initialized(e.g, static field or static initializing block).

Make sure whether all libraries are located in lib directory when you run the servlet.

Comment: This can be a comment, instead of answer.

Comment: Disagree. It is the correct solution to the problem that the poster is facing, perhaps caused by the class missing from the jar.

Comment: @Ai Suzuki:  I added HibernateUtil Code to above

Comment: Is hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar in your web application lib directory? also check the dependencies:

http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

I usualy get those java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when the class appears MORE THAN ONCE in the classloader.  Check the jars because, if the same class is present in more than one (maybe included both in the webservice client jar AND elsewhere) the java classloader will not know which one to load, even if it's exactly the same class.

Answer (score 0):

In the HibernateUtils, there is reference for the "/hibernate.cfg.xml" file. In which we have to add the hbm.xml mapping. also confirm that mapping file present in the resource file.