# Could not initialize class HibernateUtil while running batch job

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-batch

I think this question has been asked many times but none of those solutions seem to be working for me.
I am getting the below error in my weblogic server.

> "Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.cs.pta.util.HibernateUtil"

The issue is, this error does not happen every time. The same piece of code works perfectly fine most of the times and throws intermittent exceptions. One thing I observed is, this error happens when I try to run a scheduled batch job (Spring Batch). (But that code also works fine most of the times).
I am using hibernate core 4.1.4.Final jar and creating sessionFactory using buildSessionFactory method of HibernateUtil.

Below is the full error stack-trace:

```
Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.cs.pta.util.HibernateUtil
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Post your code as well, to let others help you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860762/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-xxx-xxx-xxx-hibernate